# Let left div wrap its conent before right div is moved under the left one

Tags: css, html, tablelayout

How do I implement [**this layout**](http://jsfiddle.net/fFkNW/) (which is build using a table) with DIVs?

Basically I want to have two divs on the same line: Div1 and Div2. Div1 should be aligned to the left, Div2 – to the right. Div2 has also minimal width being set. When the width is not enough for both of them then Div1 one must wrap its content giving space to Div2. Whatever I have tried the Div2 always was moved under the Div1 before the content of Div1 was wrapped.

So I came up with solution made with a table. How to build same layout using DIVs?

---

Solution with a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
#table {
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#div2 {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td id="div1">This text should wrap when window is made smaller.
      <td id="div2">This takes 30% but not less than 250px;
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your question, "how to do this without using tables at all?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/fFkNW/3/

I changed the markup to use `divs` and updated the CSS to use `floats`

If you make the window smaller, you can see the red box start to wrap around the green box.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="div2">This takes 30% but not less than 250px.</div>
  <div id="div1">This text should wrap when window is made smaller.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#div2 {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 250px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to replicate the output from the table using more semantic markup. Your output is different.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something like this. I need to test it a little bit more...

Comment: Wow! The key was to change the order of divs declaration. When trying myself I didn't try swapping divs. Your solution solves my problem exactly as I wanted it. However it is not exact layout from the question because the some pieces of the text from the left Div1 may go under the Div2, which is not possible with a table.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  </div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}
```

Didn't test it, but it shall work.

Regards.

Comment: This doesn't look like #left will wrap around #right http://jsfiddle.net/fFkNW/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fFkNW/ - it doesn't wrap here. And it shouldn't. Why do you think it should? You're not the person asking the question.

Comment: It doesn't work. The right div (green) jumps down when the window gets smaller. Your HTML is not valid, please fix it, to let me be sure that I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [CSS box-flex](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/).

Answer (score 0):

One of the most high fidelity ways to do this would be to simply use divs displayed as a table:

```
#table {
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: table;
}
#table > div {
  display: table-row;
}
#div1, #div2 {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GNXAf/) that it looks exactly the same.

Comment: Based on the example you link to, the content in the red box doesn't wrap the content in the green box.

Comment: @TimBanks See my comment on your answer. To quote the OP: "How to build **same** layout using DIVs?". You are doing something entirely different.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution requires additional divs to be added which makes it more like a workaround. Theoretically it is correct answer to my question but I was looking for a true way of building same layout with divs.